# Solutions for $p$ where $2 p^2 - 1 = q^2$

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

Consider this equation:

$$2 p^2 - 1 = q^2$$

where $p$ and $q$ are prime.

*After vigorous checking, I couldn't find any solutions $p>29.$*

*Is it so that $p=5,\;p = 29$ are the only solutions?*

**Edit:**

Found solutions $p>29$ with the help this.

The solution for $p,q$ can be expressed as:

$$\begin{align}p &=a_n= {1\over4} \left(2 (3-2 \sqrt{2})^n+\sqrt{2} (3-2 \sqrt{2})^n+2 (3+2 \sqrt{2})^n-\sqrt{2} (3+2 \sqrt{2})^n\right)&\\
q &=b_n=- {1\over2} \left((3-2 \sqrt{2})^n+\sqrt{2} (3-2 \sqrt{2})^n+ (3+2 \sqrt{2})^n-\sqrt{2} (3+2 \sqrt{2})^n\right)&\end{align} $$

thus:

$$\begin{align}
2 p^2 - 1 = q^2\rightarrow\text{True}&\implies\\
p = a_n,\;q=b_n,1<n\\
\end{align}$$

So when both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are both primes, then $2 a_n^2 - 1 = b_n^2$.

Solutions for $n$ I've found so far are:

$$\begin{align}
n=2&&a_n = 5&&b_n = 7\\
n=3&&a_n = 29&&b_n = 49\\
n=15&&a_n = 44560482149&&b_n = 63018038201\\
n=30&&a_n = 19175002942688032928599&&b_n = 19175002942688032928599\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: $2p^2 -1 = 49$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson ... and $2p^2-1=7^2$.

Comment: The integer solutions of $2x^2-y^2=\pm1$ are of the from $x_n=\frac1{\sqrt  2}(1+\sqrt 2)^n-\frac1{\sqrt 2}(1-\sqrt 2)^n$, $y_n= \frac1{2}(1+\sqrt 2)^n+\frac1{ 2}(1-\sqrt 2)^n$ or something like that. The question is whether primes appear among these.

Comment: Yes sorry, I misread.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Based on your comment, I found a closed forms for $p,q$. Will edit to reflect. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 more solutions, you just haven't searched far enough

[OEIS A163742](http://oeis.org/A163742) gives solutions $(63018038201, 44560482149)$ and $(19175002942688032928599, 13558774610046711780701)$. It is conjectured that these are the only 4 prime pairs.

Comment: I figured that out just now. I've edited to show how.

Comment: @JohnWO Note that the search was done up to $n=1000$, and there were no other prime pairs found.